# Is there a way to set something like `GIT_OPTIONAL_LOCKS=0` on a per-repository basis?

Tags: linux, git, sync

**Use case**: I am using Git to track history of personal notes that are automatically synced between my computer and my phone (via Syncthing). I use `git status` before committing from a different device than last time to be sure that everything has been synced.

**"Solved" problem**: The problem is that `git status` updates the index, creating sync conflicts and (depending on which device "wins" the conflict) losing commits. (The correct files are there; they just have new extensions of `sync-conflict-[timestamp]-[random code]`. It's annoying to resolve manually.)

**"Solution"**: From `man git-status` I found out there's a `--no-optional-locks` argument. Per `man git`, this is the same as setting `GIT_OPTIONAL_LOCKS=0` (e.g., exported from `~/.profile`). This works great at preventing me from accidentally creating a synchronization conflict.

**Unwanted side effects**: Unfortunately, `GIT_OPTIONAL_LOCKS=0` in `~/.profile` is global to the device / account where it's set, as opposed to being local to the repository that actually needs it. This means that the environment variable applies even to large repositories that I'm not syncing, where the background index refresh may be a significant performance gain.

**Sought solution**: Thus I think that a per-repository `GIT_OPTIONAL_LOCKS=0` setting would fix my problem cleanly. Is something equivalent possible?

**Alternative approaches**: Maybe it's wrong for me to use Git within a synchronized folder in the first place and this entire approach is doomed to chronic problems. If so, then is there a better approach, something like a simple way to sync a repository between devices from within Git itself? At minimum, after initial setup, I am looking for a list of commands that I can make into a script to securely sync the repository between devices (by running the same sync script on both) while they're connected to the same (untrusted) local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should not use per-file cloud syncing services to sync Git repositories.  There are several reasons for this:

- These services sync file by file.  However, a Git repository's integrity requires that some files (e.g., objects) be written before others.  Similarly, blobs must be written before the trees which reference them, or the repository is corrupt.  These services don't understand this ordering and don't guarantee it, and they don't provide the required POSIX semantics.
- These services tend not to gracefully handle conflicts as files change on both sides.  This can cause problems for the index and other files within the `.git` directory, but also in the working tree.  Git does not want another service to create random files in the `.git` directory, and you can end up with a large number of weird refs, among other problems.
- These services sync the repository in a non-quiescent state.  It's fine to use something like `rsync` on a repository, but only in a quiescent state, since Git will have written all of its objects properly into the file system.  However, usually cloud syncing services monitor for any changes and upload them immediately, which is not safe.
- Git stores system-specific information, such as device and inode numbers, into the index by default.  Since this data will almost certainly differ between systems, anything which refreshes the index must read the entire working tree since the data is stale.  (Using `rsync` has this problem as well.)  Git's security model doesn't permit sharing a working tree across users who don't trust each other (like users on different systems), so fixing this is not considered important.  In addition, removing some of this data from the index can lead to cases where `git status` doesn't properly detect changes.

If you want to securely sync two repositories with working tree, your best bet is to use SSH and rsync when the repository is in a quiescent state.  You're probably going to want to use `--delete-after` in addition to make sure you don't lose data.  You may also want to set `core.trustctime` to `false` and `core.checkStat` to `minimal` to avoid serializing device-specific data into the index; note, however, that this may lead to Git not detecting some changes with `git status`.

As to your original question, the answer is that Git doesn't provide a way to do this, but you can of course make `git` a shell function that does the right thing if you want.  As I've explained, there are better ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks! You've given me a lot to research towards my solution. One clarifying question: Is there a reference for Git's "required POSIX semantics" so I can be sure I'm not missing a key requirement?

AFAICT, Syncthing preserves as much metadata as possible between connected systems (I've already set `filemode = false` to account for Android limitations), and it's possible to control Syncthing from the command line (for a Git-wrapping script to pause syncing when the repo isn't "quiescent"), so there's no fidelity advantage with `rsync`.

I'm looking up the Git settings you mentioned.

Comment: This is the [text from POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) I'm referring to: “Writes can be serialized with respect to other reads and writes. If a read() of file data can be proven (by any means) to occur after a write() of the data, it must reflect that write(), even if the calls are made by different processes.”  I strongly recommend you explicitly perform a sync in a quiescent state and don't rely on tools to guess correctly, and I will tell you that the Git developers will be more sympathetic to rsync-related issues than issues with other tools.

Comment: POSIX: I meant is there a reference for what Git specifically requires? If it's just read/write serialization, then letting syncing finish before switching devices suffices. As far as Git knows, I could be doing "`rsync` the `.git` repository [and working directory]" per https://stackoverflow.com/a/1400758/619001. `sync`: There's no guessing if the filesystems' `read()` and `write()` are reliable; if they're not then `sync` can't be trusted either. Conclusion: The Git settings you mentioned, "ensure quiescence before switching devices", and "write a wrapper script" answers my question. Thanks!